# IntelliJ Idea - Go to File > Why having to press Ctrl+Enter to open found file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I remember I could search a file with **Go to File** function (Ctrl+Shift+T) and just press Enter to open it after typing its name.
Now typing Enter only isn't enough and I have to press Ctrl+Enter to open the file. Do you know how to change this behaviour?

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: Hi, it was my fault because I overwritten some keystrokes behaviors.
Thank you